# Mapping backend's properties to frontend properties

Tags: json, dictionary, angular, typescript

Suppose we have the following result from backend:

```
{
    idPerson:string, 
    name: string
}
```

Now I have a typescript class:

```
class Option {
    id: string;
    text: string;
}
```

So, the backend is giving me the following:

```
"[{idperson: "1", name: "foo"}, {idperson:"2", name:"bar"}]"
```

when I receive the answer from an angular http request I am doing the following:

```
let options: any[] = [];
options = JSON.parse(response);
```

So it gives me:

```
[{idperson: "1", name: "foo"}, {idperson:"2", name:"bar"}]
```

But I really want to map the keys from backend to the frontend keys and obtain:

```
[{id: "1", text: "foo"}, {id:"2", text:"bar"}]
```

How can I map them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let options: Option[];
options = JSON.parse(response).map(item => ({
  id: item.idPerson,
  text: item.name
}));
```

In the case you don't need any methods in the Option class I would create an interface instead.

```js
interface Option {
  id: string;
  text: string;
}

let options: Option[];
options = JSON.parse(response).map(item => ({
  id: item.idPerson,
  text: item.name
}));
```

If you do need methods on the Option class though:

```js
class Option {
  constructor(public id: string, public text: string) {}

  public doSomething() {
    console.log(this.id)
  }
}

let options: Option[];
options = JSON.parse(response).map(item => new Option(item.idPerson, item.name));
```